# C program to ask for two separate files then displays number of characters, lines and words

Tags: c

I am writing a program to do this but have error messages. I have changed the fopen-s line to what it is now but this message appears after entering the two file names? 
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ1jj.png)

here are no error messages that come up in visual studio but not sure if this is not the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
//setting names of ints and chars.
FILE *file_in;
int wordcount, linecount, charcount;
char letter;
char filename1[50];
char filename2[50];

//setting all counts to 0.
wordcount = 0;
linecount = 0;
charcount = 0;

//Gets the user to enter name of file, then puts it in string.
printf("\n Enter first text document\n");
gets_s(filename1);
printf("\n Enter second text document\n");
gets_s(filename2);

//opens then reads the first file.
fopen_s(&file_in, filename1, "r");

    // counts the number of words, then lines, then letters in doc 1. 
    while ((letter = getc(file_in)) != EOF);
    {
        if (isspace(letter) && !isspace(getchar()))
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
        if (letter == '\n');
        {
            linecount++;
        }
        if (letter == '-')
        {
            charcount++;
        }
    }

    //opens then reads the second file.
    fopen_s(&file_in, filename2, "r");

    // counts the number of words, then lines, then letters in doc 2.
    while ((letter = getc(file_in)) != EOF);
    {
        if (isspace(letter) && !isspace(getchar()))
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
        if (letter == '\n');
        {
            linecount++;
        }
        if (letter == '-')
        {
            charcount++;
        }
    }

    //displays the total on screen.
    printf_s("Words:", wordcount, "\n");
    printf_s("Letters", charcount, "\n");
    printf_s("Lines", linecount, "\n")
```

}

Comment: `errno_t fopen_s(   
   FILE** pFile,  
   const char *filename,  
   const char *mode   
);` So maybe you really want `fopen_s(&file_in, filename1, "r");`

Comment: When you ask questions here, you need to include all the information. What is the error? Was it a compiler error or runtime? How did you narrow it down to that function? If you have an error message, copy the whole thing into the question.

Comment: Just [use the standard functions and ignore the warnings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx)

Comment: Probably not the reason for your crash, but you are aware that you have extra `;` at the end of each of your `while` lines? That means both are empty loops, followed by a standalone block, rather than the loops you think they are.

Comment: Also, have the you checked that your `fopen_s` calls are successful (return 0, and populate the file handle with a non-null value?

Comment: the syntax for `gets_s()` is : `char *gets_s( char *str, rsize_t n );`  Notice there are two parameters and the posted code is only showing one parameter.  I.E. the code will not compile.  Please post code that actually compiles.  Also, always enable all the warnings when compiling then fix those warnings/errors.

Answer (score 0):

fopen_s takes 3 arguments. First is pointer, to which you want to assign the file, second is filename and third is how you want to acces file ("r", "w", etc)

Answer (score -2):

A few things I found to change here... This code worked for me:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "ctype.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //setting names of ints and chars.
    FILE *file_in;
    int wordcount, linecount, charcount;
    int letter;
    char filename1[50];
    char filename2[50];

    //setting all counts to 0.
    wordcount = 0;
    linecount = 0;
    charcount = 0;

    printf("Enter first text document: ");
    fgets(filename1, 50, stdin);
    ch = filename1;
    while(*ch != '\n')
        ch++; 
    *ch = '\0';
    printf("Enter second text document: ");
    fgets(filename2, 50, stdin);
    ch = filename2;
    while(*ch != '\n')
        ch++; 
    *ch = '\0';

    //opens then reads the first file.
    file_in = fopen(filename1, "r");

    // counts the number of words, then lines, then letters in doc 1. 
    while((letter = fgetc(file_in)) != EOF)
    {
        if (letter == ' ')
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
        else if (letter == '\n')
        {
            linecount++;
        }
        else
        {
            charcount++;
        }
    }

    //displays the total on screen.
    printf("File 1...\n");
    printf("Words: %d\n", wordcount);
    printf("Letters: %d\n", charcount);
    printf("Lines: %d\n", linecount);

    //opens then reads the second file.
    file_in = fopen(filename2, "r");

    //reset counts
    wordcount = 0;
    linecount = 0;
    charcount = 0;

    // counts the number of words, then lines, then letters in doc 2.
    while((letter = fgetc(file_in)) != EOF)
    {
        if (letter == ' ')
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
        else if (letter == '\n')
        {
            linecount++;
        }
        else
        {
            charcount++;
        }
    }

    //displays the total on screen.
    printf("File 2...\n");
    printf("Words: %d\n", wordcount);
    printf("Letters: %d\n", charcount);
    printf("Lines: %d\n", linecount);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what problem you are encountering with it?

Comment: I need to change all the printf to printf_s and when I do this to fopen to fopen_s it says: errno_t cannot be assigned to an entity of type file. And 
char is incompatible with parameter of type file. And too few arguments in function call.

Comment: Why do you need to change printf to printf_s and fopen to fopen_s? What happens if you try to run the code with printf and fopen instead of printf_s and fopen_s?

Comment: it says its unsafe and to change it to that? Its also because its bit of coursework and didnt want it not to work when I hand it in.

Comment: I believe that the compiler stating it is unsafe is just a warning. If so, it does not mean that the program will not run. It should be possible to ignore the warning and compile and run the program anyway.

Comment: Ive found out how to do this now its saying gets is undefined

Comment: Check out my edited post. It turns out that gets was disabled in some compilers, and instead you have to use fgets. However, fgets results in having to do a little more string manipulation. Basically, for each file name, I'm reading in up to 50 characters from the user from stdin, and then going and turning the newline into a null terminator so that the character arrays each contain only the filename we want, without any newline at the end.

Comment: put this line at the beginning of each file: `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`  Then the visual studio compiler will not issue those (silly) warnings about functions that can be abused.

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for many years and in the latest version of C, is completely eliminated.  Strongly suggest using `fgets() instead

Comment: Do not casually change from one function to a similarily named function without first carefully reading/understanding the man page for the new function.